# WinRT Check PointerPressed outside of Control

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, focus

I have a Control called ListViewControl and I have a ListView inside this Control. The ListView is toggleable (the function for this is called ListToggle()).

How can I check if the User has clicked (or pressed, in case of Touch usage) outside of the ListViewControl, so I can call ListToggle() there?

A second possibility would be to check if **everything** inside the ListViewControl has lost the focus. I can imagine it beeing something with Children Elements, but I'm pretty new to C#, that's why I can't really seem to figure it out.

ListViewControl.LostFocus doesn't work, since this event occurs everytime the focus switches to another child element inside this Control.

Sadly, I've found nothing usable. Only stuff for WPF which didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve precisely? this is very unclear. Do you want your list to be toggled when pressed, and untoggled when unpressed ?

Comment: I don't see what should be unclear. I've written that I want to check if the User clicks outside of the ListViewControl. After that Event, I'll call ListToggle(), which handles all calculations and changes. I'ts only about the PointerPressed **outside** of my Control.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FocusManager` after `LostFocus` event is raised to see who got the focus.

As for clicking anywhere - you could check for `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPressed` triggering anywhere in the app and checking if it was within the bounds of your `ListView`. Otherwise - you can put your `ListView` on a full screen `Popup` with a transparent `Grid` (make sure to set its `Background` to `Transparent` for it to be clickable/hit-test-visible) and handle `PointerPressed` on the `Grid`.

Comment: The main problem is the abstract form of my ListViewControl. Its form is somewhat like an inverted "r", where the horizontal part is the control and the vertical part is the ListView. Since I'm pretty new to C#, I do not know how to check for PointerPressed. It says it can only be used to the right of += or -=.

Comment: You can read up on C# events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). You would do something like `element.PointerPressed += this.OnElementPointerPressed;` and elsewhere define the event handler - `private void OnElementPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) { /* your logic here */ }`